# I have troubles making a forum using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

The code below is the program that i have written.
The problem is, even if i press submit, reply or delete, none of the button works.

Can you help me what is wrong with the code that i have written below.
Thank you so much.

```
<?php

/*共通処理*/

//データベースへの接続
try{
$GLOBALS['db'] = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=bbs", "root", "test");    
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'connection failed: '.$e->getMessage();
}

//action取得
$action = (isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : $_POST['action']);

//action振り分け
switch($action)
{
        //書き込み処理
    case "regist":
        proc_regist();
        break;

        //削除処理
    case "delete":
        proc_delete();
        break;

        //返信処理
    case "res":
        proc_res();
        break;

        //表示処理
    default:
        proc_default();
        break;

}

// 終了処理



/* ここで処理は終了　あとは個別の関数へ */


// 基本の掲示板表示処理
function proc_default()
{

    $db = $GLOBALS['db'];


    $page_max = 15;
    $offset = ( isset($_GET['offset']) ? $_GET['offset'] : 0 );

    $limit = $page_max +1;

    $stmd = $db->query("select * from message order by no desc limit $limit offset $offset");
    $rows = $stmd->fetchAll();

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html lang = "ja">
<head>
<meta http-equiv = "Content-Type" content="text/html; charset = UTF-8">
<title>
</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method = "POST" action = "bbs_new.php">
<input type = "hidden" name = "action" value= "regist">
お名前：<input type="text" name="name"><br>
メール：<input type="text" name="mail"><br>
題　名：<input type="text" name="title"><br>
削除キー：<input type="password" name="delkey" value="<?php print $delkey ?>"><br>
<textarea name="contents" cols="60" rows="5"></textarea><br>

<?php
print "<input type='submit' name='write' value='送信'>\n";
print "<hr>\n";
print "記事番号：<input type='text' name='delno'>\n";
print "削除キー: <input type='password' name='delkey'>\n";
print "<input type='submit' name='delete' value='記事削除'>\n";
print "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'action' value = 'delete'>\n";

?>


</form>

<?php

//ここからデータ表示処理



$sql = 'select * from message order by no desc';

foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {


    if ($_GET['resno']) {
        if ($row['resno'] != $_GET['resno']) continue;
    }

    if ($_POST['resno']) $resno = $_POST['resno'];
    else $resno = $no;
    if ($row['no'] != $row['resno']) $res = true; else $res = false;
    if ($res) print "<blockquote>";
    else print "<hr>";
    print "<p>No.".$row['no']."　";
    print "<b>{$row['title']}</b>　投稿者：";
    if ($row['mail']) print "<a href='mailto:{$row['mail']}'>";
    print $row['name'];
    if ($row['mail']) print "</a>";

    $row['time'] = date("Y/m/d H:i:s");
    print "　投稿時間：{$row['time']}";
    if (!$res && !$_GET['resno']) {
        print "　<a href='bbs_new.php?resno={$row['no']}'>返信</a>";
    }
    print "<br><br>{$row['contents']}</p>";
    if ($res) print "</blockquote>";
    print "\n";

}

//改ページ

if(count($rows)>$page_max){
    $next = $offset+$page_max;
    print "[<a href='bbs_new.php?offset=$next'>前のページ</a>]";
}

if ($offset>0){
    $prev = $offset-$page_max;
    print "[<a href='bbs_new.php?offset=$prev'>次のページ</a>]";
}

    //rowに１行ずつ取得したデータが入る




//返信データの有無
    $sql2 = 'select * from message order by no desc';

    foreach ($db->query($sql2) as $row2) {
        //入力フォームの書き出し
        if ($_GET['resno']) {
            print "<input type='submit' name='write' value='No.{$_GET['resno']} に返信'>\n";
            print "<input type='hidden' name='resno' value='{$_GET['resno']}'>\n";
        } else {
            print "<input type='submit' name='write' value='送信'>\n";
            print "<hr>\n";
            print "記事番号：<input type='text' name='delno'>\n";
            print "　削除キー: <input type='password' name='delkey2'>\n";
            print "　<input type='submit' name='delete' value='記事削除'>\n";
        }
    }
}


//header("Location: bbs_new.php");


//データベースへ書き込みを行う処理

function proc_regist(){



    // グローバル変数から取り出す
    $db = $GLOBALS['db'];

    //記事番号
    $sql = 'select no from message order by no desc';
    $maxno = 0;

    $no = $maxno + 1;


    $_POST['no'] = $no;
    if(!$_POST['resno']){
        $_POST['resno'] = $_POST['no'];
    }



    //データベースへインサート

    $sql = 'insert into message values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)';
    $st = $db->prepare($sql);
    $result = $st->execute(array($_POST['no'], $_POST['resno'],$_POST['name'], $_POST['mail'],$_POST['title'], $_POST['contents'],$_POST['delkey'], $_POST['time']));
}



       header("Location: bbs_new.php");



//データベースから削除を行う処理

function proc_delete(){

    $db = $GLOBALS['db'];
    $sql = 'delete from message where no = ? and delkey = ? ';
        $sth = $db->prepare($sql);
        $ret = $sth->execute(array($_POST['no'],$_POST['delkey']));


    header("Location: bbs_new.php");
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `header('Location: ...')` won't work if there is an output before.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try this?

```
print "<input type='submit' name='action' value='write'>\n";
print "<hr>\n";
print "記事番号：<input type='text' name='delno'>\n";
print "削除キー: <input type='password' name='delkey'>\n";
print "<input type='submit' name='action' value='delete'>\n";
print "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'action' value = 'delete'>\n"; (remove this line)
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice! But even if I remove the line you mentioned, it doesn't work.

Comment: I've just seen there are still 3 more lines whre the name of the field is action (both submits) and also: <input type = "hidden" name = "action" value= "regist">. Can you rename those 3 lines that they are different (namewise)? Additionally, does it throw any javascript errors when you load the page or click on one of the submit buttons?

Comment: Thank you for your kindness trying to help me. I rename and tried it again but it still doesn't work. and this program is written with php and mysql, so it doesn't give javascript errors.

Comment: I also have other question which is, inserting the data to the database process is not working with the above program where I wrote proc_regist. Is there anyone who can help me on this question? thanks you.